# How to install your own bundle with Composer in Symfony 2.1?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I've just moved to Symfony 2.1, and I can't understand, how can I install my own bundles with Composer?

It was very easy in 2.0.x in `deps`:

```
[MyOwnBundle]
  git=git@git.weboshin.ru:weboshin_cms_bundle.git
  target=/bundles/My/OwnBundle
```

After that I just triggered `bin/vendors update` and that was it!

But now there's no `deps` file, and I supposed to do everything with Composer. Please give me any hints.

Comment: **With Symfony 2.1 you can also use the old dependency manager!** You have to create a `composer.json` file to tell Composer what are your dependencies. You should look at [Symfony Standard Edition's one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json). Then create another `composer.json` for your bundle.

Comment: @Florent, please be aware that there is already a tag for the Composer tool, `composer-php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the answer.

```
// my_project/compose.json:
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "own_repository_url"
        }
    ],

    // ...

    "require": {
        // ...
        "own/bundle": "dev-master"
    }
},
```

```
// own_repository/own_bundle/compose.json:
{
    "name": "own/bundle"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a composer.json file to your bundle. For example I have this for one of my bundles:

```
{
    "name":        "cg/kint-bundle",
    "type":        "symfony-bundle",
    "description": "This bundle lets you use the Kint function in your Twig templates. Kint is a print_r() replacement which produces a structured, collapsible and escaped output",
    "keywords":    ["kint", "debug", "symfony", "bundle", "twig"],
    "homepage":    "http://github.com/barelon/CgKintBundle",
    "license":     "MIT",

    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Carlos Granados",
            "homepage": "http://github.com/barelon"
        },
        {
            "name": "Symfony Community",
            "homepage": "http://github.com/barelon/CgKintBundle"
        }
    ],

    "require": {
        "php":                      ">=5.3.2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": ">=2.0.0",
        "raveren/kint":             "dev-master"
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev",

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Cg\\KintBundle": ""
        }
    },

    "target-dir": "Cg/KintBundle"
}
```

Then add your bundle to [packagist.org](http://packagist.org). It is very simple, basically you just have to provide your git address and it will do the rest.

Once your bundle is available in packagist, then just add it as a dependency in the composer.json file for your symfony project. In my case I have:

```
"require": {
    ....
    "cg/kint-bundle": "*"
},
```

Then just run "composer update" in your symfony directory and that´s all! You don´t even need to update the autoload file, composer will do it for you. The only thing left would be to load the bundle in appkernel.php

Comment: Note that "adding to packagist" is only valid for open source bundles, for closed source ones, refer to https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs and https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md

Comment: Does anyone know what the `symfony-bundle` implies ? What are the consequences of using this type ?